# On zooming In MapView button doesn't detect tap in custom callout in ios

Tags: ios, mkmapview

Hi Everyone,
            I have customized callout bubble in MapView, i have added one UIButton in callout bubble. it detects tap on tapping on it, but when i start zooming In MapView and and tap the button , it doesn't detect Tap on it.
Any help would be appreciated!